# Migrated Spring boot 1.5.x t0 2.3.x and one endpoint not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-rest

I have migrated spring boot 1.5 to 2.3 every thing is working except 1 endpoint that is returning error : "org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 :"No converter for [class java.util.ArrayList] with preset Content-Type 'null' could any one please let me know what might be the issue

Comment: I would suggest you migrate from 1.5.x to 2.0.x, then 2.1.x, then 2.2.x and finally 2.3.x. Avoid giant leaps of faith and migrate in smaller steps. Also check the migration guide from 1.5.x and 2.0.x https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide and 2.1 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes), 2.2 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes) and 2.3 release notes (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Content-Type in the request is null.  My assumption would be that in the earlier version, Spring had a default converter that was being used and now they're being more explicit.  Assuming that you are sending json, try setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and see if that solves your issues.

Comment: I have tried by adding Content-Type to application/json but still its not working